# Multiple ways of factoring a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm wondering if there are multiple ways to factor polynomials of degree $3$ or higher.

For example, the polynomial $27x^9+81x^8+135x^7+162x^6+144x^5+99x^4+53x^321x^2+6x+1$ can be factored into $$(3x^3+3x^2+2x+1)^3$$
And can also be written as $$x^3+(3x^2+2x+1)^3+(3x^3+3x^2+2x)^3$$
So I'm wondering if there are other similar polynomials that can be rewritten two different ways.

Comment: The second form is *not* a factoring of the original polynomial.

Comment: @dxiv Hm... Then how should I word the problem?

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of other polynomials like that. Play with WolframAlpha and you'll find a bunch.I found this one:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-5)%5E2(x-3)%5E4.

Comment: @Crescendo Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean to ask. If it's simply that polynomials can be written in "different" ways, then that's obviously true, for example all of $x^2 + 2 x + 1 = 1 + x(2 + x) = (x+1)^2$ represent the same polynomial.

Comment: And much more possibilities if beside $+$ also $-$ is allowed.

Comment: All things can be written in multiple ways.  But if you mean to actually factor, the fundamental theorem of algebra might be more clear.

Comment: Perhaps a better question might be "Can anything interesting be said about polynomials which can be written as a sum of cubes of polynomials?" or a sum of squares, etc. Your example is a polymomial which can be written as the sum of cubes in two different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any polynomial can be expressed in infinitely many different ways in the sense of your example. For example, we can write $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=f(0)+x\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)$$
In this form it looks a little silly, but $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ is actually a polynomial itself. So, for example, 
$$50x^{39}+300x^2+1=1+x(50x^{38}+300x)=1+x^2(50x^{37}+300)$$

If we're really just talking about factoring a polynomial as a product involving no additional sums, then there is only one way to factor the polynomial into polynomials that cannot themselves be factored further (over the integers, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, etc.). In asbtract algebra parlance we'd say that the polynomial rings over these coefficient rings are unique factorization domains.

Judging by the context of your question you probably haven't encountered the beautiful topic of abstract algebra yet, but you may be interested to know that in this sense your question is studied extensively in more generality in an advanced setting.

Comment: Yes, I have not gotten even close to Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @Crescendo It's my favorite subject. If you are a math major or planning to be one, or even if not, I highly recommend it once you have the prerequisites. Theoretically the only prerequisite is basic set theory and logic, but realistically it helps to have seen a lot of math, even if it's unrelated (like calculus).

Comment: Cool! But do you know if you learn it in college? I kind of would like to be something other than a math major. Math major is like, choice number $3$...

Comment: @Crescendo If you want to learn it in school, you learn it in college. It'd be required for a math major, but you could take it as an elective even if you pick another major. You could also always get a textbook and learn on your own, but you might want to start with something more elementary. Honestly, if you want to get ahead, studying outside of school is the best thing you can do for yourself, regardless of your major. And when you take a course, read ahead of where you are in class. It's worth the extra time. School will be so much easier.